# Universal variable for objects in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I have an TextView in my android studio project. I want to access it. I know it can be done through

```
val myText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
```

but everytime I make new function I need to declare val of myText using above code line. Like This:-

```
fun onDigit(view: View){
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.append((view as Button).text)
}

fun onClear(view: View){
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.text = ""
}
```

Is there any way to universally declare it and access it without declaring it in every function?

Comment: make it `lateinit var` class level field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can keep a reference to your view in a property from the activity or fragment. It will look like this:

```
// Declare the view as property
private lateinit var myText: TextView

// Then in onCreate save a reference to it
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     ....
     myText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
}

// After this point, you can access the view as any global variable
fun onDigit(view: View) {
    myText.append((view as Button).text)
}
```